# Apache Ranger 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: unable to install and configure HDFS plugin

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-ranger

I've installed ranger-admin and ranger-usersync for apache hadoop-2.7.7. When I try to install, ranger-hdfs-plugin for the same, the service for the same isn't listed on ranger-admin UI (under service manager). The **install.properties** file for ranger-hdfs-plugin is provided below:

```
    POLICY_MGR_URL=http://localhost:6080
    #
    # This is the repository name created within policy manager
    #
    # Example:
    # REPOSITORY_NAME=hadoopdev
    #
    REPOSITORY_NAME=hadoopdev
    #
    # Set hadoop home when hadoop program and Ranger HDFS Plugin are not in the
    # same path.
    #
    COMPONENT_INSTALL_DIR_NAME=

    # AUDIT configuration with V3 properties
    # Enable audit logs to Solr
    #Example
    #XAAUDIT.SOLR.ENABLE=true
    #XAAUDIT.SOLR.URL=http://localhost:6083/solr/ranger_audits
    #XAAUDIT.SOLR.ZOOKEEPER=
    #XAAUDIT.SOLR.FILE_SPOOL_DIR=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/audit/solr/spool

    XAAUDIT.SOLR.ENABLE=false
    XAAUDIT.SOLR.URL=http://localhost:6083/solr/ranger_audits
    XAAUDIT.SOLR.USER=NONE
    XAAUDIT.SOLR.PASSWORD=NONE
    XAAUDIT.SOLR.ZOOKEEPER=NONE
    XAAUDIT.SOLR.FILE_SPOOL_DIR=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/audit/solr/spool

    XAAUDIT.HDFS.ENABLE=true
    XAAUDIT.HDFS.HDFS_DIR=hdfs://ubuntu3.dap.com:9000/ranger/audit
    XAAUDIT.HDFS.FILE_SPOOL_DIR=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/audit/hdfs/spool

    #
    # Custom component user
    # CUSTOM_COMPONENT_USER=<custom-user>
    # keep blank if component user is default
    CUSTOM_USER=hdfs


    #
    # Custom component group
    # CUSTOM_COMPONENT_GROUP=<custom-group>
    # keep blank if component group is default
    CUSTOM_GROUP=hadoop

    XAAUDIT.DB.IS_ENABLED=true
    XAAUDIT.DB.FLAVOUR=MYSQL
    XAAUDIT.DB.HOSTNAME=localhost
    XAAUDIT.DB.DATABASE_NAME=ranger_audit
    XAAUDIT.DB.USER_NAME=rangerlogger
    XAAUDIT.DB.PASSWORD=rangerlogger
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this would be done in the HDP hadoop distribution. As you can see there are multiple steps, and I suspect you may have skipped one.

1. Enable ranger
2. Update dependent configurations
3. Restart everything

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_security/content/hdfs_plugin.html